# SUM not showing expected value in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table as

```
ID  TOTAL SUM(TOTAL)
1   62    62
1   53    53
2   62    62
2   47    47
```

I thought the SUM(TOTAL) should look like

```
ID  TOTAL SUM(TOTAL)
1   62    115
1   53    115
2   62    109
2   47    109
```

This is the query I used

```
select ID, TOTAL, SUM(TOTAL)
from tablename
GROUP BY TOTAL, ID
```

Comment: what database engine are you using?

Comment: @Lamak: irrelevant. there's nothing in that query that would be server-specific.

Comment: @MarcB Not irrelevant at all, there are ways to do this that have better performance than the standard join, but go ahead and answer then

Comment: question isn't about performance, it's about unexpected results.

Comment: that's what **you** are reading about the question. The results aren't "unexpected" at all if you understand the query, op is getting the right results

Comment: Okay I don't know much about Oracle but I see the Window Functions continue to get voted down, I suspect because of specific version of oracle then?  because this article suggests oracle has them: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174

Comment: @Lamak the results are unexpected from the OP's perspective which is how most people would read it. But sure, you are technically correct.

Answer (score 3):

You could do a windowed `SUM` instead:

```
Select   ID, TOTAL, SUM(TOTAL) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) 
From     tablename
```

This will give you the results you expected.  It will display the `ID` and `TOTAL` for each row, along with the `SUM` of the `ID` grouping.

A `GROUP BY` is not necessary for this type of summation.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to remove the `TOTAL` column from the group by, and therefore the select list. Because `TOTAL` is in your select list and group by it can't properly aggregate how you're expecting.

```
SELECT ID, SUM(TOTAL)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY ID
```

To get your exact output:

```
SELECT tablename.ID,
       TOTAL,
       TOTALSUM
FROM   (SELECT   ID,
                 SUM(TOTAL) AS TOTALSUM
        FROM     tablename
        GROUP BY ID) AS t
       INNER JOIN
       tablename
       ON tablename.ID = t.ID;
```

Comment: It's possible to get OP's desired output without sacrificing the `total` column. Window Functions, subquery, or rollup would work depending on the DBMS.